# Using value in a cell as destination cell address(Indirect copy)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do roughly the same thing as `=INDIRECT()` in google sheets, but using google script.

Here is my code:(not working)

```
function save_to_base2() {  //function desauv de edition2 vers base2
 var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('edition2');
 var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('base2');
 var refdest = sheet1.getRange('B337');//
 var source = sheet1.getRange('B336');// source a sauv ds base
 var dest = sheet2.getRange(refdest);
 source.copyTo(dest, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

- In `refdest`, I have the string "A136" (cell ref where i want to write)
- In `source` I have the string "hello John"

I want to copy the `source` value(string) to `dest`, where `dest` is the indirect value of `refdest`.

Comment: Please elaborate on how does it not working? Also if there is any particular error message

Comment: the error is "array not found" line 7
in french Plage introuvable (ligne 7, fichier "Code")

Comment: That is because you are trying to use `getRange()` using another `getRange()` result as the parameter. Please refer to the documentation on how to do that. Also, you might want to check the value of each `getRange()` result

Comment: I tryed to find info on how to do that but I didn't found any idear on how to use a getrange result in an another getrange any guess or sample code doing that?
Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column

Comment: any guess of working code to do that?

Comment: with get values?
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
var values = range.getValues();

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, so please read the documentation, follows the tutorials, learn from the sample code in that documentation, go through other off-site tutorials, or try it by yourself

Comment: Yes. `sheet2.getRange(refdest.getValue());`

Comment: The Master,Thanks a lot , it works, i was stuck with the getrange + getvalue syntax, that's all I needed, thanks

Comment: Thanks also to JSmith,
but it's ok now, merci pour la proposition d'aide, peut_être une prochaine fois
Philippe

Answer (score 1):

now the working code looks like that: and it works, thanks a lot

```
function save_to_base2() {  //function desauv de edition2 vers base2
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('edition2');
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('base2');
var refdest = sheet1.getRange('B337');//cell B337est = à "A139"
var source = sheet1.getRange('B336');// source a sauv ds base 137
var dest = sheet2.getRange(refdest.getValue());
source.copyTo(dest, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```